# Variable defined in script tag can't be accessed from other files in the project

Tags: javascript

So in the head tag, I have the following code:

```
<script>var test = ${serialize({firstName, surname})}</script>
```

In another file, called config.js I have the following.

```
    export default {
    firstName: test.firstName,
    surname: test.surname,
};
```

Now when I run npm lint, it gives me the following error for:

```
 2:15  error  'test' is not defined  no-undef
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `window.test`. Your linter doesn't know about `test`, so it thinks you're just trying to access an undefined variable. And make sure the inline script is above your bundle script (or use `defer` for the bundle script).

Comment: yup you're right, just adding window fixed the issue